# On SharePoint Online, is there a way to restict users to have access to SharePoint Online ONLY if they are at the physical office location?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

On SharePoint Online, is there a way to restict users to have access to SharePoint Online ONLY if they are at the physical office location?

The stakeholders only want to permit admin to have remote access but all other users must only have access to SharePoint Online if they are in the office building with their account.
Is this possible?
Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would guess that your Office network would have a specific IP address range, so based on that you can restrict access.

If your stakeholders also want admins to be able to access remotely, then they can add individual admin team member's remote IP address range as well.

References - [Control access to SharePoint Online and OneDrive data based on network location](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/control-access-to-sharepoint-online-and-onedrive-data-based-on-network-location-b5a5f1f1-1174-4c6b-91d0-9273a6b6971f)

[Conditional Access by Network Location for SharePoint and OneDrive for Business](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/Introducing-Conditional-Access-by-Network-Location-for/ba-p/39274)

Answer (score 2):

If you pay for Azure AD Premium license then you can use [Azure Active Directory Conditional Access](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-conditional-access-azure-portal)

Comment: Thank you as well Per Jakobsen, I wish I could have checked your reply as the answer as well.